# Canonical url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I'm using https://example.com version of url for my laravel built app [site](https://upscaleadventures.com/).

I want
 `<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en-us" href="https://www.upscaleadventures.com/" />` as my canonical tag

`{{url()->current()}}` only gives the URL that I've setup as default.  `<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en-us" href="https://upscaleadventures.com/" />` version in my case.

How do I print https://www.upscaleadventures.com/ version of url in Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set `APP_URL` in your `.env` file to  https://example.com, then access it via

```
env("APP_URL", "somedefaultvalue");
```

**Edit**

You may consider create a [helper](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) to convert your URL

```
function addWwwToUrl($url) {

   $bits = parse_url($url);

   $newHost = substr($bits["host"],0,4) !== "www." ? "www." . $bits["host"] : $bits["host"];

   $newUrl = $bits["scheme"]. "://" . $newHost . (isset($bits["port"]) ? ":" . $bits["port"] : "" ) . (isset($bits["path"]) ? $bits["path"] : "" ) . (!empty($bits["query"])? "?" . $bits["query"]: "");

   return $newUrl;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789067/add-www-to-url-in-string)

**Usage**

```
{{ addWwwToUrl(url()->current()) }}
```

Comment: That only gives url for index page. What about other dynamic pages ??

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your desired result and show us what have you tried that we could look.

Comment: Updated Question

Comment: @TanjaForsberg check demo Repl here https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/Canonical-url-in-laravel

Comment: Can you check my site ?? `<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en-us" href="{{ addWwwToUrl(url()->current()) }}" />` Code in my frontend

Comment: what does return url()->current()  for you ?

Comment: Fixed, Recheck pls